# Which follows or which followed?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I am writing a report and comparing this year's increase/decrease to last year's increase/decrease.

Which of the following sentences is more correct and why?

> Civil filings decreased 21.6% in 2020, to 19,655 from 25,076, **which
> follows** a 13.5% decrease in 2019.

vs

> Civil filings decreased 21.6% in 2020, to 19,655 from 25,076, **which
> followed** a 13.5% decrease in 2019.

Comment: i would use _following_ - but whatever are civil filings?

Comment: @KateBunting probably "the filing (or lodging) of complaints of civil offences" as a guess.

Comment: yes, I work for a court and working on our annual report of civil and criminal filings.